# How is Iron Man communicating with the others on Titan?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War* Star Lord is implanted with a translator. But how are Iron Man and Spiderman able to communicate with others on Titan...

Comment: Just speculation, but if most people in the 'wider universe' has translators (2-way), including Drax and Mantis?

Answer (score 2):

As @iandotkelly mentions, Drax and Mantis are very likely to have universal translators as well. They are interstellar travelers part of a multi-species team, it is probably safe to assume that all the Guardians (except Groot) have translators. Groot doesn't have one, and this may be due to him being a plant based being rather than the more...fleshy teammates, as translators are implanted beneath the skin.

Comment: Groot does more or less seem able to understand everyone just fine.  His failures to do so seem to be more indicative of him being stupid, or simply thinking in such a completely different way that it's hard for him to grasp the concepts (even if he is otherwise reasonably smart). There are multiple scenes where characters have a conversation with him without talking in groot.